# I can't use the Calendar as a User in my Browser

Tags: firefox, select, datepicker, calendar

I use a calendar in My program (a web application) and I open the app with Firefox browser, now I have a problem with it; The calendar doesn't work on some client's browsers. The version of all browsers is the same, but the datepicker of the calendar can't open on some system's clients. After clicking on datepicker all of the system components don't work and I have to close application.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Fix some spelling.